# Working with strings in C that contain multiple Null characters

Tags: c, linux, memory

I have a `char[]` buffer that contains data read from the memory, which means there are multiple Nulls within this buffer and not only one single terminating Null at the end.

```
char *addr = (char *)memmem(buff, strlen(buff), needle, strlen(needle));
```

I need to process this string and search and replace certain content.
For this, I would like to use `memmem()`, but unfortunately, it's not working because the multiple Nulls within the buffer.

I tried to replace the Nulls in the buffer with a character from which I thought it would not appear (the Bell ASCII code \7) and then process it, but this does not work and corrupts my data.

Is there another way to process a string that has multiple Nulls?

Comment: A C string has only one `\0` and it is at its end. A char array containing any value is not a string and `<string.h>` functions cannot be used on it.

Comment: Please don't cast the return value of `memmem()` in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memmem` can be used to do it. However, since your data contains embedded nulls you cannot use `strlen` to calculate the length. You need to keep track of the lengths separately.

```
char *addr = (char *)memmem(buff, buffLen, needle, needleLen);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `strlen` on your char array that, by your own admission contains terminating isn't going to work. You should realize that `strlen` just counts the number of chars up to the point where it encounters a zero terminator.
Incidentally, this is how `strncat` works, too, so you can't use those functions either.

What you could do is keep an `int` at hand which you use to keep track of the *actual* length of the string.
An other way of tackling this problem would be to write your own `d_strlen` function, and always ensure that your buffer has *two* zero-terminating chars at the end:

```
size_t d_strlen(const char *in)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while( !(in[len] == '\0' && in[len+1] == '\0' )) ++len;
    return len;
}
```

Again: your `buffer` *Must* then be terminated by *two* terminating zeroes, not just the one:

```
char buff[100] = "this \0 string contains \0 terminators \0";//adds second \0
printf("%d  != %d\n", strlen(buff), d_strlen(buff));//yields 5 != 37
```

---

As Frerich Raabe pointed out, to *not* loose the optimizations and security of a tried 'n tested function like `strlen`, this might be a better version of `d_strlen`

```
size_t d_strlen(const char *in)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while(strlen(in+len)) len += strlen(in+len) + 1;
    return len ? --len : 0;//check for zero-length
}
```

However, this calls `strlen` twice, which is pointless overhead, so you're probably better off writing this:

```
size_t d_strlen(const char *in)
{
    size_t i, len = 0;
    do
    {
        i = strlen(in+len);//get substring length
        len += i + 1;//add to total length + 1 for \0 char
    }while(i > 0);
    return len > 1 ? len-2 : 0;//subtract 2, if possible, else return 0
}
```

Comment: Given that `strlen` is usually a heavily optimized function, it would probably be more efficient to reuse it (i.e. call it repeatedly for each string and summing up the results) instead of iterating yourself, byte-by-byte.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: fair point, added another implementation of the `d_strlen` function that uses `strlen`

Comment: Cool, +1 from me, except that you call `strlen(in+len)` twice for each substring. :-}

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I know, that bugged me, too. So I've updated it to only call `strlen` once for each substring

Comment: Looking better! Now if you could change `int` to `size_t` (since that's what `strlen` returns)... :-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: hop-scotch... I haven't been writing C for that long, and haven't encountered any issues with different implementations, so I haven't been confronted with the _real_ reasons for these implementation-specific types. I'll edit, though. thanks for your time and effort, giving me feedback and reviewing on this little function.

Comment: Sorry for being so pedantic. `int` vs. `size_t` *does* make a difference on 64bit builds (in which case `size_t` is 64bit, but `int` may be 32bit, so `int i = strlen(..)` gives a truncation warning).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: No, really: I welcome criticism like this. Coming from a scripting-language background, it's exactly these kind of _"gotcha's"_ that have me scratching my noodle all too often. At least now I bothered to google longer than 2 seconds to understand the reasons behind `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` types. Why they are used, and what might happen if you don't use them... the _thanks_ in my previous comment was sincere, not sarcastic

Answer (score 0):

A C string is a sequence of chars terminated by a NUL ... by definition it can't contain more than one NUL. What you have is something more generic, a block of chars. To deal with arbitrary blocks of chars, they must be accompanied by a length -- the count of the number of chars. Given that you can process the block without any concern for whether it contains NULs. Given a block consisting of a pointer to some chars and the count, you would use the count, rather than strlen, so

```
memmem(buff, buff_len, needle, needle_len);
```

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I've written in C for 35 years and was on the C Standards committee and I disagree with your epistemology and pedantics, but I won't get into a detailed debate about it with you.